# Why did it take so long for China to admit there was human-to-human transmission, are there political or legal reasons?

Tags: china, covid-19

Why did it take so long for China to admit there was human-to-human transmission and are political or legal reasons the reason(s) why they took so long? I see a lot of sensational news claiming China purposely decided to not share information about human-to-human transmission to the rest of the world to let the virus do as much damage as possible to other countries, but I am thinking there was a political reason that motivated the Chinese authorities to not do so.

Comment: Related if not a straight duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/52901/could-the-ccp-have-disclosed-the-covid-19-pandemic-much-earlier-as-the-u-s-clai

Comment: When COVID-19 struck, academia was dominated by 唯论文 ("paperism": almost total focus on publications), which gave rise to incompetent "experts" whose skills lie in publishing large numbers of papers.  Academia in China is [now](http://www.most.gov.cn/kjzc/zdkjzcjd/202003/t20200305_152137.htm) [undergoing](http://www.most.gov.cn/mostinfo/xinxifenlei/fgzc/gfxwj/gfxwj2020/202002/t20200223_151781.htm) [reform](http://www.moe.gov.cn/srcsite/A16/moe_784/202002/t20200223_423334.html) and this is part of the motivation.  I'm not sure why, but this doesn't get much coverage in English-language media.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use loaded language like the word "admit". Think fairly. It is not obvious that any new virus can transmit from human-to-human. How would you tell that the virus can transmit from human-to-human anyway? The obvious way is to infect someone then lock that someone in a room with an uninfected individual, but of course nobody would want to participate in that kind of experiment. The other way would be to find someone with no possible contact to a wild host who nonetheless comes down with the illness, which of course takes time (don't forget that there's also a non-negligible incubation period of around 14 days for the virus, plus it's possible to test positive but be asymptomatic). Therefore given that it takes time to show that the virus can transmit from human to human, naturally they are going to say there is no evidence it can. Note "there is no evidence" is not the same as saying "it cannot".

If you think all this was a cover up and that it should have been clear that human-to-human transmission happens, try answering this question: Can asymptomatic carriers spread the virus? For that matter, how long after exposure does a carrier become "live" and can spread the virus?

Here's [a relevant quote](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-52232147):

> Prof Teo says it's easy to say with hindsight that it was a mistake to not limit returnees' interactions. But the reality is "right now, we know a lot more about the disease compared to back in March".

... and Wuhan went into lockdown in *January*. If we know a lot more about the disease now compared to March, just think how much information the Chinese authorities had when they made that fateful decision.

> China purposely decided to not share information about human-to-human transmission to the rest of the world to let the virus do as much damage as possible to other countries

You realize that China suffered tens of thousands of cases with thousands of deaths, and its economy went into a recession for the first time in decades, because of the virus right? That they put Wuhan into lockdown well before the virus was spreading happily in Western countries? And you're saying it's possible they *intentionally* allowed the virus to spread to cause damage to other countries? The theory is as nonsensical as saying the US orchestrated 9/11 so it can invade Iraq and get cheaper oil.

**If your country was bad at stopping the virus, do not blame China, blame your government.**